# NodeJS XMPP over WebSocket server

Tags: node.js, websocket, xmpp, node-xmpp

Title really says it all, I've looked through github and npm and can't find anything still updated or even what I'm looking for at all that can do this. Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build the server yourself in Node.js, you can use `ws` module to handle incoming WebSocket connections and then handle incoming packets using `xmpp.js` module. There is an [example in xmpp.js repository](https://github.com/xmppjs/xmpp.js/commit/56d7132df6653ef0777658fbc7d07588fd74279e).

If you are looking for a full fledged server implemented in Node.js with support for WebSocket, you should go to [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) as this is a site for questions related to software development.